# How to overcome subquery in Hive for CASE statement

Tags: hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I have to populate the column value to 'Y' if the condition is true, Or else 'N'. But as in hive it does not support subquery in case stetement , how can this be return in HIVE.

```
(case
  when exists
  (select 1
  from fntable fs
  join dfntable dfs
  on fs.id = dfs.id
  and dfs.datetime = 
     (select max (cd.datetime)
      from dfntable cd group by id)
  and fs.s_id = dfs.s_id)  then 'Y'
else 'N')"
```

Comment: Please provide data example for both tables and desired output example

Answer (score 1):

Using subquery with analytic function + left join. When joined then 'Y':

```
select case when cd.id is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end 
  from fntable fs
      left join
      ( --group by  cd.id, cd.s_id and filter 
       select cd.id, cd.s_id 
         from
            ( select max (cd.datetime) over (partition by dc.id) as max_id_datetime,
                     cd.id, cd.s_id, cd.datetime
                from dfntable cd
            ) cd
        where cd.datetime=max_id_datetime --filter only records with max date
        group by cd.id, cd.s_id
      ) cd on fs.id = dfs.id and fs.s_id = dfs.s_id
```